# KonvaJS Fill Rect with two colors?

Tags: colors, rect, konvajs

It is possible? If yes how? One example please.

```
var example = new Konva.Rect({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    width: 500,
    height: 20,
    fillLinearGradientStartPoint: [0, 0],
    fillLinearGradientEndPoint: [400, 0],
    fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, 'red', 1, 'yellow']
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API for fillLinearGradientStartPoint and fillLinearGradientEndPoint is not correct. A correct example:

fillLinearGradientStartPoint: { x : -50, y : -50},

fillLinearGradientEndPoint: { x : 50, y : 50}

Question

Why I received two negative votes?